# Saving and reading kwargs from a file

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I know how I can save kwargs in a .txt file.

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        file.write("{}: {}\n".format(key, value))
```

Let's says `kwargs = {'page': 1, 'name': 'xyz', 'title': 'xyz'}`

But how can I read the file and save the data back to kwargs how it was before it got saved to the file so that the result is `kwargs = {'page': 1, 'name': 'xyz', 'title': 'xyz'}` after reading the file?

Comment: well you could try to read the file and build up a dict that you pass as kwarg back to a function

Comment: Saving this way, you will run into ambiguity when you read back the output, as integers could be interpreted as strings consisting of only digits.

Comment: well he asked how to go about building it back out of the file, how you parse the the values is a totally different set of problems. if you want to do that too you open up a box of possible solution to do so which in it self is a question of its own i guess.

Comment: Do you know about the configparser module? https://pymotw.com/3/configparser/  It's unclear why you're doing what you're doing, but I think that you may want to reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're okay with saving it in a slightly different format, you can use the in-built `eval` function.

Writing your dictionary to a file:

```
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(str(kwargs))
```

Reading your dictionary back from the file:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    kwargs = eval(file.read())
```

Comment: Are there any security implications in retrieving the `dict` this way? It's just an evaluation, so I'm assuming the worst you can get is a thrown exception. If format didn't matter, wouldn't just pickling it been the safest and cleanest way?

Comment: Rather than use a raw `eval` you can use `ast.literal_eval` which is "safer" for "reasons".

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't necessarily *recommend* this approach if you're reading anybody else's file -- but the original post implied he was saving a dictionary for his own usages, and also implied that his dictionary was in a format where serialising it was unnecessary for the purposes of saving it to a text file.

If you pickled it, you could be sure of being able to represent complex python objects in your dict (which you obviously can't if you're just saving it as plaintext), but pickle is just as insecure -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KnfGDajDQw&ab_channel=PyCon2014.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't concerned about the ambiguities, this would be the inverse of what you presented in your question:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    kwargs = {}
    for ln in file:
       key, _, value = ln.partition(': ')
       if value.isdigit():
           value = int(value)
       kwargs[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is the simple way to go about that, and before we get to the talk about ambiguity with that its simply to show how you could extract what you save in the file. it will be a key/value pair with key and pair are both strings. to cast the value part into the correct type isn't the scope of the solution

the test.txt content:

```
foo: bar
bas: buz
```

the code example:

```
result = {}

with open("/home/mr/test.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        k, v = line.replace('\n','').split(':')
        result.update({k.strip(): v.strip()})
```

the content of result dict:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'bas': 'buz'}
```